# Hide Show Toggle Button Image

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, show-hide

So I'm relatively new to coding and I've been trying to put a toggle button to hide/show an image. However, I'd like it to start out as hidden and then show after the click rather than its current state of showing first.

I tried using `visibility="hidden"` but that just made the image a blank space that was still "showing". If anyone could help me out/help me rework my code, it would be greatly appreciated!

here's what I've been working with:

```
<button type="button" button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="$('#imgname').toggle();">view</button>
<div id="imgname">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/imgsource">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aleksei's answer is pretty much correct but I think you wanted the div to be hidden at first, yeah? The best way to do that is using CSS. Changed the HTML a little bit:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunyweasel/64f688kn/) here for you, this shows you how it works :)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="$('#imgname').toggle();">view</button>

<div id="imgname">
<img class="img" src="images/imgsource">
```

jQuery (Aleksei's code):

```
  $(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
   $("img").toggleClass("hidden");
   });
 });
```

then the CSS, if you're not sure how to use CSS then comment and I'll help you out :)

```
 #imgname
 {
 display:none;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! For some reason though when I put it into my code (I'm using Espresso & bootstrap) it's not having the same effect as it does on jsfiddle. I am most likely doing something wrong with the CSS

Comment: Nevermind! I tinkered around and eventually got it to work- thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at my computer when you replied ^^ Glad you got it working :) Make sure you choose the best answer by clicking the green tick when asking a question on here.

Answer (score 2):

add this jquery code

```
$(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
       $("img").toggleClass("hidden");
   });
});
```

change html

```
<button type="button" button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" onclick="$('#imgname').toggle();">view</button>
<div id="imgname">
    <img class="img-responsive hidden" src="images/imgsource">
</div>
```